# System.err.println fails under threads pressure in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I'm writing a program using java, where I use some error printing statements for debugging.
My program generates about 2000 threads. The program runs fine till the moment when a large number of threads access this statement:

```
System.err.println("Some error message");
```

When this happens one of my threads successfully manages to get access to println function, while the other threads have status:

> State in JVM: Waiting for synchronized block

Digging deeper in the debugging statement I noticed that the thread which managed to access println function is stopped at this function:

```
private native void writeBytes(byte b[], int off, int len , boolean append) throws IOException;
```

and it has the following stack trace:

> java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:327)
>
> java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
>
> java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
>
> java.io.PrintStream.write(PrintStream.java:482)
>
> sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:221)
>
> sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:291)
>
> sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:104)
>
> java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flushBuffer(OutputStreamWriter.java:185)
>
> java.io.PrintStream.write(PrintStream.java:527)
>
> java.io.PrintStream.print(PrintStream.java:669)
>
> java.io.PrintStream.println(PrintStream.java:806)
>
> fetcher.responseHandler.ExtendedResponseHandler500.handleResponse(ExtendedResponseHandler500.java:20)
>
> fetcher.FetchWorker.run(FetchWorker.java:79)
>
> java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

While the other threads are stopped at the first line of the println function (inside the java core code):

```
synchronized(this)
```

Is this problem caused by me? or is this error related to JVM? Can I do anything about this issue?

Comment: Could you show some code and/or stacktrace?

Comment: Let's back up a second... why on earth does your application need 2000 threads?

Comment: @JoeC It's running on a server, not my local PC. These threads' job is to fetch pages from the internet, and I need to get a full use of my internet connection bandwidth.

Comment: May I suggest that you consider dividing those 2000 threads across multiple (dozens, if not hundreds) of JVMs.  `System.err` is not designed to be able to handle that many threads at once.

Comment: @JoeC Thank you, I will try to modify my threads' hierarchy then.

Comment: Re, "My program generates about 2000 threads."  That's probably not a good thing.  2000 _sequential_ threads?  You probably should be running a _thread pool_ instead.  2000 concurrent compute-bound threads?  Your computer probably does not have 2000 CPUs on which to run them.  2000 concurrent threads all _waiting_ for something?  What are they waiting for?  If your're running a server with 2000 simultaneous clients, it might be time to thing about building a _cluster_.

Comment: @jameslarge I mentioned before that I use this number of threads to get a full use of my internet connection bandwidth. These threads are used to fetch html pages from the internet and store them in some data structure. I noticed that 2000 threads uses almost the full bandwidth of my internet connection, while 200 threads for example doesn't.

Comment: You can run `jstack -m` to see what's going on in the native code above the last java frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely cause is that the output stream of the process isn't being consumed by the parent process, so the stdout buffer fills up and then the next call to System.err.println just hangs forever.

This is common when one process is used to launch another, but doesn't set up "flushing" threads to drain the child's stdout and stderr streams.

Note that this doesn't have anything in particular to do with "threading" - but launching many threads can certainly increase the rate at which errors are generated (and perhaps cause more total errors if something else fails due to contention downstream) which means your output buffer fills up faster and hangs earlier.

Comment: My program is multi-threaded not multi-processed, I don't think that this issue holds with multi-threaded programs. Am I right?

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with multi-processing. It doesn't even have much to do with multi-threading (except that multiple threads get you to the "buffer full" condition faster). It simply depends on where you have `stderr` piped to. Are the errors showing up on the console or has it been redirected somewhere? How is the processed launched?

Answer (score -1):

It is perfectly normal for 2000 threads to be waiting to acquire lock on the println call.

Your stack trace shows that you are getting some HTTP 500 errors. Probably the majority your threads got this error and now are all in line to report it on the standard error. What you are seeing is the consequence of your problem, not the cause.

2000 threads is an insane number, it will not improve performances for about any reasonable scenario and will most likely degrade performances. Start with something like 4 and see if incrementally doubling that value gives you any improvement. The JVM can handle this number of threads (so this is NOT the source of your problem) but it is just useless. Using more JVM will not fix the problem (that is probably a simple HTTP 500 and/or network timeouts).
Also check the server side logs.

If you need to maximize performances (in a real high concurrency scenario) consider asynchio, but normal IO is extremely good for all common cases and seems fine here.

**Update:**
My hypotesis is this:

1. a thread does a remote call
2. it gets a 500 error
3. it joins the line to report the error behind other 2000 threads
4. it succedes and goes back to point 1

The step 3 may take a lot of time so even taking multiple thread dumps you will see the very same thread that appears always locaked (I mean that you need to be very lucky to see the Thread-1352 during the steps 1 or 2). I'm assuming that you checked the thread name and that the locked thread we are discussing is always the same.
Do you see any log while the program "freeze" (does it freezes, right?) or everything is still? How many thread dumps did you took, how much time in between?

Comment: First of all `ExtendedResponseHandler500` is a class created by me, when it counters a problem it's supposed to report it.

My problem is not with the HTTP 500 error, my problem is that when a huge amount of threads are all in line to report it on the standard error, one of them managed to access println function, and the other threads are waiting to get access.

The main problem is that this one thread is hanging, it doesn't finish using system.err, causing other threads to be blocked for ever.

Comment: I can see no obvious reason for the write method of  java.io.PrintStream that you are calling to block forever. One remote possibility is that you added somewhere else a "synchronized(System.err)" acquiring the System.err monitor in a different context. Do you see any activity while the thread freeze? or everything is still? I've updated my answer.

Comment: Actually it does exactly as I said, just freezes forever (I tried waiting for many hours, nothing happened). Also, I didn't use "synchronized(System.err)" in any part of my code. I know that the expected behavior is as you mentioned in your updated, but it doesn't happen that way, that's the actual reason of my question.

Comment: Did you check if the thread executing the writeBytes() is always the same in multiple thread dumps taken at a few minutes of distance? How do you execute the program (inside an ide, command line)? operating system?

Comment: I execute the program inside NetBeans IDE. the thread executing writeBytes() is not always the same, in fact, it's almost always a different one.

Comment: So what you are seeing from the debug window is normal: one thread inside the synchronized block and the others waiting in line. The fact that you see different threads means that the program is still running, is not in deadlock or the like. Maybe the problem is the Netbeans output console, I'd try to run it outside. Do you have enough other output visible or a log file? Is this other output on the std err too? Maybe you do not see any activity because the program is extremely slow and there is not enough output too in the relevant places (the error 500 handling part) (even after many hours).

Comment: @SaeedSryheni are your threads anonymous classes or lambda? If so, it may be the HotSpot optimizer doing a massive work on them. This is triggered after the program has been running for a while. Try to run it with -XX:+PrintCompilation -verbose:gc to see what is going on while the program "halts".